# RegEx for Twitter username not working

Tags: php, regex, twitter

The following regular expression function for validating a Twitter username is not working because a twitter name can be a minimum of 1 character and a maximum of 20. However, when I tested this, it allows usernames greater than 20 characters. Where did I go wrong?

```
public function val_username($subject)
{
    return (bool)preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}/', $subject);      
}
```

Comment: You need to add `^` and `$` at the start and end, to match the start and end of the string - otherwise, it'll match any set of 1-20 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `$` and `^`

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}$/` should work

```
public function val_username($subject)
{
    return (bool)preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}$/', $subject);      
}
```